# Overflow after multiplying positive int8s and casting to uint32

Tags: go, integer-overflow

I am trying to multiply 8-bit positive integers and cast the result to `uint32`.

```
a := int8(12)
b := uint32(a * a) // 4294967184
```

In the above code multiplying causes an overflow.
But if I **cast each int8 to uint32/uint8 before multiplying**, I get the expected result like below,

```
b := uint32(uint32(a) * uint32(a)) // 12
```

Why do I need to cast before multiplying?

Does the code get executed something like this?

```
tmp := a*a
b := int32(tmp)
```

Or is there something else?

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_overflow

Comment: Your question answers itself in the first line: "multiply 8-bit positive integers and cast the result". You multiply, which overflows, *and then* cast the result.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to answer itself, but for clarity:

Think of the grammar of a type conversion as being the same as the grammar of a function call. The expression inside the parameters is fully evaluated, and then it is passed to the function.

If you do

```golang
math.Sin(f*f)
```

You wouldn't expect it to be equivalent to

```golang
math.Sin(f) * math.Sin(f)
```

You need to cast *before* multiplying, because 12 * 12 is not a safe operation in signed 8-bit values.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense now.
Thank you very much for the clarification.